# reading html file input and sending to node.js for processing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm using **node.js** for a basic form-processing task.

The html file loads, but when I submit the form, it fails to process.

Here is the code I'm running right now:

**formhandling2.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('peanuts.html');

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res){
var userName = req.body.userName; 
res.send ('Hello: ' + userName + '.<br>' + '<a href="/">Try again.</a>');
res.sendfile('peanuts.html');
});

app.listen(80);
```

**peanuts.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forms></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        form action="/myaction" method="post">
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="..." />
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have an invalid HTML file? (peanuts.html)

Comment: What does "fails to process" mean? Error message or what?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your server file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('peanuts.html');
})
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res){
var userName = req.body.userName; 
res.send ('Hello: ' + userName + '.<br>' + '<a href="/">Try again.</a>');
res.sendfile('peanuts.html');
});

app.listen(80);
```

See above, after res.sendfile('peanuts.html') you have to close }) braces.

then you have **html syntax error**  you have not started form tag. Correct code below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forms></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/myaction" method="post">
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="..." />
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

everything else works nice i tested once fixed